# Read each line of txt file to new array element and open links php

Tags: php

i have names.txt

for example:

```
name1 n\
name2 n\
name3 n\
name87 n\
name4e n\
```

and i just to curl this get method by line array of name.txt

```
php.com/test.php?name=name1
php.com/test.php?name=name2
...
php.com/test.php?name=name3e
```

all of array of in the name.txt

my code is

```
$test = file_get_contents('name.txt'); // i need to use all name array in name.txt
```

and open it in while to php open website by all name in the name.txt

and end after the name complete in name.txt and while to stop

```
file_get_contents($test');
```

thanks

Comment: Look at `file()` which reads a file into an array all in one go. [See manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a php function called `file()` that read all the lines of a file into an array, so removing your need to make an array from a newline delimited string read with `file_get_contents()`

```
$lines = file('name.txt');

// Loop through our array, and build (n) cURL connections
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    // Do your cURL stuff in here
}
```